# Blender text editor and the 'insert' key

Tags: scripting, text-editor

I don't know how but in the *Text Editor*, as I was editing a script, I disabled inserting (i.e. keystrokes overwrite current text instead of inserting a new character). how do I re-enable it?

I've tried:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
- Clicking <kbd>Insert</kbd>  on the on-screen keyboard
- Restarting Blender
- Opening a new script

Comment: For me pressing *insert* on the keyboard toggles this behavior

Comment: have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 1):

You pressed the <kbd>insert</kbd> key on your keyboard. It's traditionally above the <kbd>delete</kbd> key. This is common behavior, and will do the same thing in other applications as well. Pressing this will toggle between 'insert mode' (normal mode) and 'overwrite mode.'

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, stuck on overtype, pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> didn't help.

The shortcut keys behavior in Blender dictates that it only work when the mouse cursor is inside the designated window boundaries.

When I hovered the mouse over the text editor, pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> just worked.